# how do i set up a project folder in vscode and link all cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

i'm new to cpp and just moved to classes, but now im stuck here wondering how do i link 2 or more cpp files to make a project(main.cpp - for main, abc.h - for defining class , abc.cpp- for defining methods outside the class). For now i use the command `g++ main.cpp abc.cpp -o main` to link all the files but as my project grows larger it will become more tedious to enter all the file names.Some guy here told if i create a project i should be able to compile as usual without compiling manually.So how do i do that in vscode?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be easy (this is why I don't recommend it for beginners), see the [common questions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview). It seems to depend on what components you have installed.

Comment: Vscode has no notion of projects (at least not without extensions). I suggest reading about [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) and [cmake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake).

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the concept of makefile, and especially cmake which will help you for your compilation problem.

Answer (score 0):

For bigger projects you can use makefile for compiling easily and faster. So in vs code I recommend you to use this extension. [VS Code C/C++ Makefile Project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adriano-markovic.c-cpp-makefile-project&ssr=false#overview)

Firstly,

> C/C++ Make: INIT Project

After,

> C++ Project

In makefile you can customize your settings.

Also you can watch this tutorial video to understand easily this process in vs code [Debugging Makefile Project with Visual Studio Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VpiGwp8Vos&list=PLKMOdY6Bhga7BUgPca5EX1J-JYQIbX5fn&index=10)